# UInavigationbar with back button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have uiviewcontroller with navigation bar and a back button on him,and i try to set a method for this back button with this :

```
UIBarButtonItem *rButton = [self.navigationItem leftBarButtonItem];
[rButton setAction:@selector(cancelCheck)];
```

and when I press the back button this method won't call

Comment: You might avoid a lot of this by using a UINavigationController, which automatically handles back buttons, then you just add custom behaviour into viewWilDisappear or viewDidDisappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the target to `self` (or whatever object that has the `cancelCheck` selector)

```
[rButton setTarget:self];
```

Comment: weird, the docs are pretty clear about the target and action properties behavior... can you provide the selector code or check if the rButton is nil? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW34

Comment: are you sure the selector is not receiving an parameter and the code should be something like `[rButton setAction:@selector(cancelCheck:)]` with the extra `:` in the selector name?

Comment: try `UIBarButtonItem *rButton = [self.navigationItem backBarButtonItem];`

Comment: @MTA let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2114/discussion-between-felipe-sabino-and-mta)

Answer (score 2):

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelCheck)];
```